# Using cURL and phpQuery error

Tags: php, phpquery

This is my code:

```
    <?php 

require('phpQuery.php');

function download($url)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array
    (
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false
    ));

    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
}

$pagina1 = phpQuery::newDocument(download('http://google.com'));

$logosrc = pq('img#hplogo').attr('src');
echo $logosrc;


?>
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function attr() in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\new\extract.php on line 26

Who know where is the problem?

Comment: Well, what does `pq('img#hplogo')` resolve to?

Comment: select from downloaded html img with id="hplogo"

Comment: No, that is what it is meant to resolve to. I ask what it _does_ resolve to. What type inside php? Is it really an object with a method 'attr()'? I doubt that. That is why I asked: dump the result and see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$logosrc = pq('img#hplogo').attr('src');
```

To be

```
$logosrc = pq('img#hplogo')->attr('src');
```

I think, but I haven't tested it.

[Look here for more info](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Attributes)

Comment: exactly, `.` is concatenation in php, but it is an object accessor in js

Comment: phpQuery is a port of jQuery accessors, but the language does not allow it to be an exact replica

Comment: In that case you're picking the wrong selector or something. But if this answer solves the error, please mark it as accepted.